# CollapsingToolbarLayout custom animation

Tags: android

Need help in using CollapsingToolbarLayout. I have download an App from play store which show nice animation when we click on Image in `toolbar`

The below image shows Toolbar before animation
[image]

When I click on image or any where in Toolbar,following things happens

1...`TabLayout` goes down

2... A view animated from  toolbar's bottom

3.. The Image in `toolbar` nicely animated to anchor position of toolbar.

below Image shows Image after animation
[image]

I don't know how to do this as imnew to animation. do I have to do with `View.OnlayoutChangeListener()`?

I will be glad to hear from you people

Comment: Have a look at [scene transition animation](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html).

Comment: I think it will be done using CollpasingToolbarLayout